# Getting values from time indexed pandas dataframe for a specific time within the two timestamps

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have the following pandas dataframe df:

```
                     C1  C2   C3
Date                             
2000-01-01 00:00:00   2  175  160
2000-01-01 01:00:00   4  192  164
2000-01-01 02:00:00   6  210  189
2000-01-01 03:00:00   8  217  199
2000-01-01 04:00:00  10  176  158
```

from which I need to get the value of C1, C2 and C3 for a specific datetime:

```
import datetime
my_specific_time = str(datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0))
print(df['C1'].loc[mytime]) # prints 4
```

The problem is that I can only get values for the dates stored in the df. For example, getting the value of `C1` for time `2000-01-01 01:30:00` is not possible unless I resample my dataframe:

```
upsampled = df.resample('30min').ffill()
my_specific_time = str(datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1, 1, 30, 0))
print(upsampled['C1'].loc[mytime]) # again prints 4
```

Please note that all the value of `C1` between timespan of `2000-01-01 01:00:00` and `2000-01-01 02:00:00` is `4`. Now the problem is that `my_specific_time` can be any random time and I would need to resample df using small enough values to be able to get the value for. I think this is not the best solution for this problem.

While looking for possible solutions I only came across [time spans](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html) in pandas but I did not quite understand how possibly I can use it in my problem.

Comment: try `.asof` : `print(df['C1'].asof(my_specific_time))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.asof.html) method:

```
print(df['C1'].asof(my_specific_time))

4
```